# how to render smarty after a jquery ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, smarty

I am using openinviter to retrieve contacts from gmail which works great.However, when I use jquery with ajax call to submit a form that retrieves contacts smarty does not render. It seems that smarty only renders a page reload which I don't want to do. So, my question is how can I make smarty render after jquery ajax call?

jquery ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('input[name="Submit"]').click(function() { 
 var query = $('#frmContact').serialize();
  $.ajax({type: "POST",url: "google_friends.php",data: query,cache: false,success:function (html) $('#errid').html('<span style="font-size:12px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#FF0000;">'+html+'</span>').show();}});        
    return false;});});
</script>

    <div>
    <!--- Smarty code that needs to render after jquery ajax call -->
    {if count($contacts) == 0 }
     <span id="errid" >{$msg}</span>
       <p>
     <!-- Form that is used by jquery ajax -->

    <form class="Form StaticForm" id="frmContact" action="" name="frmContact" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="provider_box" value="gmail" />
                <ul>
                    <li>
                       <input type="text" name="email_box" value="email" onBlur="if      (this.value=='') this.value='email';" onFocus="if(this.value=='email') this.value='';" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                       <input type="password" name="password_box" value="password" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='password';" onFocus="if(this.value=='password') this.value='';"  />
                    </li>

                    <li class="noBorderTop"><input class="Button WhiteButton Button18 trueB" type="button" value="Submit" name="Submit" />
                        <label>
                            &nbsp;</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </form>       
    </p>
         <!-- smarty code that needs to render after ajax call -->
         {else}
         <span id="errid" ></span>
          <p>
         <form class="Form StaticForm2" action="" name="invtfrm" method="post">
               <ul>
                    <li style="float:left;margin-left:120px;">                          
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkall" onClick="return doCheckAll();" style="vertical-align:0" />&nbsp;Select All

                    </li>
                    <li style="float:left;"><div class="box-dividerCenter1 gradient"></div></li>  
             <!-- smarty code that needs to render after ajax call -->   
             {foreach from=$contacts key=fkey item=fval}

                <li style="float:left;margin-left:120px;">                          
                    <input type="checkbox" name="email[]" value="{$fkey}"  style="vertical-align:0"/>&nbsp; 
            <!-- smarty code that needs to render after ajax call -->
                {$fval}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{$fkey}

                    </li>   
                       <li style="float:left;"><div class="box-dividerCenter1 gradient"></div></li>     
           {/foreach}
            <li class="noBorderTop"><a class="Button WhiteButton Button18" href="#" id="sbmtbtn" ><strong>Invite</strong><span></span></a></li>
    {/if}
    </ul>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a logical error in your assumption.

Smarty is *only* used when the page is actually loading (or reloaded), but *not* when an ajax request with jQuery (or other js frameworks) is answered. Basically the variable `$contacts` will only get checked when the page loads, but *not* because of some response events in your javascript code.

One of the main reasons of using ajax-techniques is actually avoid reloading pages.

Two better approaches:

1. Use your javascript to change the content of your html containers.
   The [jquery manual section of .ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) has a few examples
   on how to do it. Just declare some empty div-containers and fill
   them with your desired data.
2. You can also fetch a whole smarty-template via ajax ([`fetch()`-method](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.fetch.tpl)) and return it. This way you'll archieve a better separation between program logic and layout.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to fetch a smarty template using ajax? Here is what I got but won't work.                        $(document).ready(function(){
 $('input[name="Submit"]').click(function() { 
 var query = $('#frmContact').serialize();
  $.ajax({type: "POST",url: "google_friends.php",data: query,cache: false,success:function (html) $('#errid').html('<span style="font-size:12px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#FF0000;">'+html+'</span>').show();jQuery("#contactResponse").fadeIn('slow').load('{include file="contactResponse.tpl"}');
}});        
  ;});});

Comment: Please look into both links in my answer to your question, they show you how its done in jquery and how you fetch a template in php.